# Passing event handlers to separate classes in Java

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, jframe

I am making a strictly multiplication calculator and I'm not really experienced with event handlers in Java. 
 
I'm not sure why the textfields are not updating on button presses.
I have to follow an Model View Controller programming structure so I can't have the buttons and the event handlers in the same class which I'm sure would make this much easier. Here's the two involved classes: 
View:

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.awt.*;

public class CalcView extends JFrame {
    public static final String INITIAL_VALUE = "1";

    public JTextField m_totalTf = new JTextField(10);
    public JTextField m_userInputTf = new JTextField(10);
    public JButton m_multiplyBtn = new JButton("Multiply");
    public JButton m_clearBtn = new JButton("Clear");
    public BigInteger m_total; // The total current value state.

    public void CalcGUI() {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("Performs Simple Multiplications");
        this.setVisible(true);
        m_total = new BigInteger(INITIAL_VALUE);
        m_totalTf.setText(INITIAL_VALUE);
        m_totalTf.setEditable(false);

        JPanel content = new JPanel();
        content.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        content.add(new JLabel("Input"));
        content.add(m_userInputTf);
        content.add(m_multiplyBtn);
        content.add(new JLabel("Total"));
        content.add(m_totalTf);
        content.add(m_clearBtn);

        this.setContentPane(content);
        this.pack();

    }

    public void throwExcept() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(CalcView.this, "Bad Number");
    }
}
```

model

```java
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;
public class CalcModel{
    public static final String INITIAL_VALUE = "1";
    
    public void clear(){
        CalcView v = new CalcView();
        v.m_total = new BigInteger(v.INITIAL_VALUE);
        v.m_totalTf.setText(v.INITIAL_VALUE);
    }
    public BigInteger multiply(){
        CalcView v = new CalcView();
        BigInteger num1 = new BigInteger(v.m_userInputTf.getText());
        BigInteger num2 = new BigInteger(v.m_totalTf.getText());
        v.m_total = num1.multiply(num2);
        return v.m_total;
    }
}
```

Controller

```java
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class CalcController {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    CalcView v = new CalcView();
    CalcController c = new CalcController();
    v.CalcGUI();
    c.listener();


    }
  
    public void listener() {
        CalcView v = new CalcView();
        CalcModel m = new CalcModel();
        v.m_clearBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                m.clear();
            }
        });
        v.m_multiplyBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    CalcModel m = new CalcModel();
                    m.multiply();
                } catch (NumberFormatException nex) {
                   CalcView v = new CalcView();
                   v.throwExcept();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You are creating a new CalcModel in your event handler -- is that really what you want? And another CalcView in listener. You should just have one model and one view, Think.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating CalcView every time instead of passing the reference around.
For example in your main method. You should be doing:

```
CalcView v = new CalcView();
CalcController c = new CalcController(v); //See here.
v.CalcGUI();
c.listener();
```

Store the reference passed to the constructor of CalcController as a class memeber.
And use that in the listener method instead of creating a new CalcView. Similarly you are recreating your model again too.

After these edits your CalcController will look something like this:

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class CalcController {

    private CalcView view;
    public CalcController(CalcView view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CalcView v = new CalcView();
        CalcController c = new CalcController(v);
        v.CalcGUI();
        c.listener();
    }
  
    public void listener() {
        CalcModel m = new CalcModel();
        view.m_clearBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                m.clear();
            }
        });
        view.m_multiplyBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    m.multiply();
                } catch (NumberFormatException nex) {
                   view.throwExcept();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The same recreation problem exists in your CalcModel, you should be passing CalcView in it's constructor too.